# SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE only disconnects sessions when account is a database user

Tags: sql-server-2016, restore, connections

The following code creates a user that is able to restore a database:

```
CREATE LOGIN RestoreUser WITH PASSWORD = 'MyPassword'
ALTER SERVER ROLE dbcreator ADD MEMBER RestoreUser
```

This works fine and the user can restore the database, however if I want to set the database to `SINGLE_USER` and rollback any existing connections, the restore command is blocked and fails:

**Session 1**

```
/* SELECT from a table and leave the SSMS window open, leaving a sleeping SPID */
USE AdventureWorks2014
SELECT * FROM Person.Person
```

**Session 2**

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'RestoreUser'

ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2014 SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2014 FROM DISK = 'C:\Test\AW14.bak' WITH REPLACE

REVERT
```

Eventually, session 2 times out with

```
Msg 5061, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database 'AdventureWorks2014'. Try again later.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
Msg 3101, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

The following `sp_whoisactive` screenshot shows that the command is blocked:

[image]

The `sp_whoisactive` lock report for session 59 shows

```
<Database name="AdventureWorks2014">
  <Locks>
    <Lock request_mode="X" request_status="CONVERT" request_count="1" />
    <Lock request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
    <Lock request_mode="U" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
  </Locks>
  <Objects>
    <Object name="(null)">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="DATABASE.BULKOP_BACKUP_DB" request_mode="U" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
        <Lock resource_type="DATABASE.BULKOP_BACKUP_LOG" request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
  </Objects>
</Database>
```

The [Microsoft Article for SET SINGLE_USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/set-a-database-to-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-ver15) states

> To quickly obtain exclusive access, the code sample uses the
> termination option WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE. This will cause all
> incomplete transactions to be rolled back and any other connections to
> the AdventureWorks2012 database to be immediately disconnected.

and

> Requires ALTER permission on the database.

My `RestoreUser` account has the correct permissions (`dbcreator` server role gives `ALTER ANY DATABASE` permissions) but I don't know why the command is blocked, the first quote suggests all other connections would be disconnected.

I also granted `ALTER ANY CONNECTION` to `RestoreUser` but that did not help.

What I found did fix the problem, is if `RestoreUser` is a user in the database being restored (doesn't need any permissions within the database)

```
CREATE LOGIN RestoreUser WITH PASSWORD = 'ABC@123'
ALTER SERVER ROLE dbcreator ADD MEMBER RestoreUser

USE AdventureWorks2014
CREATE USER RestoreUser
```

The code

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'RestoreUser'

ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2014 SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2014 FROM DISK = 'C:\Test\AW14.bak' WITH REPLACE

REVERT
```

Then runs without being blocked by the sleeping session.

My questions are

- Why does the `SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` code get blocked when it should kill and rollback all open SPIDs
- Why does creating the user in the database fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dan Guzman originally noted, the `sp_WhoIsActive` output indicates the `RESTORE` is blocked, not the `ALTER DATABASE` command. Even so:

If the `SET SINGLE_USER` command is **uncontended**, there is no issue. The connection acquires the single `SESSION` level shared database lock that prevents anyone else connecting to the database, and life is good.

If there is **contention** (another connection to the database), there is a check to see if the security principal executing the command can connect to the database.

When this check fails, the `ALTER DATABASE` command fails and an error message like the following is returned:

> Msg 5061, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
> ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database 'AdventureWorks2017'. Try again later.
> Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
> ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

The check succeeds when:

- The principal has `CONNECT ANY DATABASE` permission; or
- The principal has a related user in the database; or
- The *guest* user in the database has `CONNECT` permission.

I don't know why this check exists, or why it only occurs if there are blocking connections. There might be a good reason, or it might be an inaccurate or obsolete test.

In some ways, it is odd that a session can acquire the single `SESSION` shared database lock associated with *single user* when the principal has no right to connect to the database.

Note also the same error occurs for the same reason if you try to set the database to `MULTI_USER` when it is already in that state and there are other users connected to the database.

On the other hand, one could argue that `ALTER ANY DATABASE` does not quite fulfil the requirement you quoted for `ALTER` permission on the specific database. Having `ALTER` permission on the database implies a user in that database because that permission can only be assigned to users, not logins. That is quite persuasive, but doesn't explain why it should only be tested when contention occurs.

All that aside, the the `ALTER DATABASE` command in your example does throw an error, but you don't check for it, or test the database is in single-user mode before continuing with the restore.

Comment: Thankyou - this clears it up. It's a shame "If there is contention (another connection to the database), there is a check to see if the security principal executing the command can connect to the database." doesn't appear to be mentioned anywhere in the documentation (or at least, none that I could find)